# Symfony3 issues with autoload_static and multiple domains

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm currently working on a project where i use one Symfony installation with multiple Domains. I managed to install the vendor in cagefs and change the dir of the vendor inside composer.json. This way i use one vendor with multiple domains.

**My issue**

It seems like the autoload only support one `$baseDir`. The autoload_static uses one directory path to `AppKernel`, `AppCache` etc.

**What i have tried**

I tried to use `$baseDir = '/home/'.exec('whoami').'/';` to generate the path each domain is using. But the **autoload_static.php** writes `/home/domain1/` after using it the first time. So domain2 will get a error `/home/domain1/...` Permission denied. My vendor dir isn't inside `/home/` but inside Cagefs so `/usr/...`. Thats why i can't use `$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);`

Is there a solution for this or is there a better way to do this?

What i want to accomplish is to share the Symfony vendor with multiple domains. This way i only need to update one time for every domain. All domains will use the same structure inside the vendor.

Comment: why not put it in one place and create soft links in 3 places? I think it should work

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? i sill use one autoload so it will result to the same issue (i guess)

Comment: What is the cost of doing 3 composer update instead of one when you need to? I don't see any value added to share the vendor between your domains

Comment: what i am trying to do is to create a CMS area for my users. I used 3 domains as example. it could eventually grow to 100 or more